# Why the value of MCD15A3H LAI is relatively low compared to the actual value?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, lai

I want to obtain the MCD15A3H LAI long time series of winter wheat samples and apply Savitzky Golay smoothing filtering to them. However, during the rising period of winter wheat, the value of LAI is relatively low compared to the actual value.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/areas/A_anyang_xuchang"),
    table2 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/areas/A_tianmen_xiantao_zaoyang"),
    table3 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/areas/A_weinan_xianyang");
var points=ee.FeatureCollection(table).merge(table2).merge(table3);
var roi=points;
print(points);

//创建一个列表
var array = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(1, 510, 1));
//将样点坐标数据导入列表并编号
var lists = points.toList(points.size()).zip(array.toList());
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(lists.map(function(l) {
  return ee.Feature(ee.List(l).get(0)).set('PID', ee.List(l).get(1));
}));

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var qcDay = image.select('FparLai_QC')
  var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
    var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit);
    var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1);
    return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask);
  };
  var qaMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 0, 0).eq(0)
  var dataQualityMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 3, 4).eq(0)
  var lstErrorMask = bitwiseExtract(qcDay, 5, 7).eq(0)
  var mask = qaMask.and(dataQualityMask).and(lstErrorMask)
  var lstDayMasked = image.updateMask(mask)
  return lstDayMasked
}

var band = ['Lai'];
var lai = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD15A3H') 
                 .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-07-01')
                 .map(maskClouds)
                 .filterBounds(roi)
                 .select(band); 
print(lai);

// 统计影像的数量
var count = lai.size();
print('Count: ', count);
// 从影像集合中获取影像时间的范围并且进行打印看看效果
var range = lai.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')));

//对LAI数据进行SG滤波平滑处理
var oeel=require('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
var sg = oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(lai,
        ee.Filter.maxDifference(1000*3600*24*15, 'system:time_start', null, 'system:time_start'),
        function(infromedImage,estimationImage){
          return ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(infromedImage.get('system:time_start'))
            .subtract(ee.Number(estimationImage.get('system:time_start'))));},
        5,['Lai']);
print(sg);

//构造函数，输出数据结果
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));
var fill = function(img, ini) {
  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);
  var ft2 = img.sampleRegions({
    collection:features,
    properties:ee.List(['PID', 'Id', 'lat', 'lon']), 
    scale:10
  });
  var date = img.date().format();
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)});
  return inift.merge(ft3);
};

// Iterates over the ImageCollection of lai
var lai_newft = ee.FeatureCollection(lai.iterate(fill, ft));
// Iterates over the ImageCollection of sg_lai
var sg_newft = ee.FeatureCollection(sg.iterate(fill, ft));

//导出到google云端硬盘
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: lai_newft,
  description: 'LAI_winter_wheat_points',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sg_newft,
  description: 'sg_LAI_winter_wheat_points',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In total, from March to May, the LAI of winter wheat is 3-8, but in the data I have obtained, the LAI of March to May is almost always less than 3.